# How can I select both test objects in my JSON string and map them to my interface?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, angular

**Question**

How can I select both test objects in my JSON string and map them to my interface called `Test`? And is it possible that my property in the interface isnt called `some_name`?

**Problem**

Im trying to map my `JSON` objects to the `Test`interface, but it does not work. The `getTests` in the component always returns undefined for

I guess the reason is that there is a parent named *test*
, but res.json().data should return only the both objects *test 1* and *test 2*.

**JSON**

```
{"test":[{"some_name":"test 1"},{"some_name":"test 2"}]}
```

**Service Method**

```
getTests() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "/something")
        .map(res => <Array<Test>> res.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**Component**

```
this.myService.getTests()
    .subscribe(
        tests => this.tests = tests,
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see there is no `data` property in the JSON content you receive.

`res.json()` returns an object containing a `test` property which is an array. You should use `.map(res => <Array<Test>> res.json().test)` instead to get the array.

Thierry

Comment: I think you mix the approach from Angular1 (`response.data`) with the one from Angular2 ;-) No worries!